# How do you iterate through a mixed List<t> and print contents to console in C#?

Tags: c#, list, iteration

I have a `List<object>` which contains strings and even additional lists.

```
List<object> NewArray = new List<object>();
```

so basically the list contains a mixture....

As a sanity check, I want to print out the contents to the console.  I start by iterating through and test to see whether the element is a list.  If it isn't then it will be a string and can be printed to the console.  If it is a list, I want to iterate through and print the string contents to the console but with a tab to indent it.

I have this so far:

```
    for (int outer = 0; outer < NewArray.Count; outer++)
            {

                var innerList = NewArray[outer];

                if (innerList.GetType().IsGenericType && innerList.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
                {

                    for (int inner = 0; inner < innerList.Count; inner++)
                    {

                        //print string
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //print string
                }
    }
```

I didn't want to use a `foreach` loop as I'm not sure the order of the list would be guaranteed and will be in the future adding a increment number (which can be provided by the inner and outer variables).

The issue I am getting is an error here:

```
inner < innerList.Count
```

which is:

> Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group'

What do I need to do to overcome this?  I'm not sure it is the most efficient way of achieving the end result but....

Comment: No, no. Check if it's non-generic IEnumerable, then cast to that and do a foreach on it. Make it a recursive method. Done.

Comment: Embrace the OOP! You're fighting the language by making a list of random crap. Create strong types for whatever you're keeping in your list. Let those types handle printing themselves by overrideing the `ToString()` method or by adding a `Display()` method or similar to the interface.

Comment: Looks like `Count` might be the IEnumerable.Count() extension method. I don't know how you made that happen if innerList is Object; could we see the complete code?

Comment: @itsme86 "Random crap" +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void Main()
{
    var randomCrap = new List<Object>
    {
        1, "two",
        new List<object> { 3, 4 },
        5, 6,
        new List<object> {
            new List<object> { 7, 8, "nine" },
        },
    };

    randomCrap.PrintAll();
}
```

Output:

```
1
two
3
4
5
6
7
8
nine
```

Using this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void PrintAll(this Object root)
    {
        foreach (var x in root.SelectAll())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Object> SelectAll(this object o)
    {
        //  Thank you, eocron
        if (o is String)
        {
            yield return o;
        }
        else if (o is IEnumerable)
        {
            var e = o as IEnumerable;
            foreach (var child in e)
            {
                foreach (var child2 in child.SelectAll())
                    yield return child2;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            yield return o;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @EdPlunkett thanks for this however the only way to get this to compile is to change `public static void PrintAll(Object root)` to `public static void PrintAll(this Object root)` and after that I get a `An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll` at the `foreach` on this line `foreach (var child in e.SelectAll())`

Comment: @cosmarchy Thanks, I'll take a look.

Comment: @cosmarchy Good catch! I got confused about the recursion. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your object is a `List<>` of some generic type, you could always cast to `IList` and loop through it that way.

To paraphrase your code:

```
if (innerList.GetType().IsGenericType && innerList.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
{
    var list = (IList)innerList;
    for (int inner = 0; inner < list.Count; inner++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(list[inner].ToString());
        //print string
    }
}
```

But in reality, you should be doing what itsme86 said, and making strong types with an overriden `ToString()` or `Display()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is more simplistic way of doing what you want:

```
public static void DeepPrint(object obj, int recursionLevel)
{
    if(obj == null)
    {
        //print null
        return;
    }
    var str = obj as string;
    if(str != null)
    {
        //print str
        return;
    }
    var enumer = obj as IEnumerable;
    if(enumer != null)
    {
        foreach(var e in enumer)
        {
            DeepPrint(e, recursionLevel+1);
        }
        return;
    }
    //print obj.ToString();
}
```

Then call it like this on whatever you desire:

```
DeepPrint(myObjectOrList, 0);
```

**PS**

For those who say about "random crap" - embrace the string.Format(...), embrace serialization in general, embrace WCF and dynamic, and etc. There is many random things in this world, what doesn't really need strong typing. In fact it will just become "crap" if you provide strong typing to some common used functions.

Comment: You fogot the indentation, but recursion was also in my mind

Comment: You're treating IEnumerable as if it were IEnumerator. That loop won't compile.

Comment: re: Random crap, agreed -- it's a ringing phrase, but when you want to trace a `List<T>`, "subclass it" isn't the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is to check if the object implements `ICollection`, and if so, iterate over the contents. I created a recursive method to handle cases where a collection contained other collections, which includes an `indentAmount` argument, so that nested collections are indented by a tab each time they're encountered:

```
public static void PrintItem(object item, int indentAmount = 0)
{
    var indent = new string('\t', indentAmount);
    if (item == null) Console.WriteLine($"{indent}<null>");

    if (item is ICollection)
    {
        var innerItems = item as IEnumerable;
        Console.WriteLine($"{indent}Collection type encountered:");
        indentAmount++;
        foreach (var innerItem in innerItems)
        {
            PrintItem(innerItem, indentAmount);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{indent}{item}");
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
private static void Main()
{
    var items = new List<object>
    {
        "first",
        2,
        new List<string> {"listFirst", "listSecond"},
        new[] {"arrayFirst", "arraySecond"},
        new ArrayList {"arrayListFirst", "arrayListSecond"},
        "third",
        new List<List<string>>
        {
            new List<string> {"nestedList1First", "nestedList1Second"},
            new List<string> {"nestedList2First", "nestedList2Second"}
        },
        4f,
        new object[] {5d, "six", new List<object>{"seven", 8} },
        9,
        "ten"
    };

    PrintItem(items);

    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]